# Git Post-receive deployment is slow

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

We are testing git version control with our websites.  The current setup has two bare repositoriees on a network shared drive /g/ (one for intranet and one for internet).  When pushing to this repository I would like to have the site automatically checked out to the webserver at /x/.  Following the suggestion of several blogs and questions here, I set up a post-receive hook as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/x/intranet checkout -f
```

This worked well for deploying the master branch of each repository.  Each deployment probably took 5-10 seconds.  However, we would also like to have a dev branch that is automatically checked out to a dev server at /y/.  My revised hook looked like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/x/intranet checkout -f master
GIT_WORK_TREE=/y/intranet checkout -f dev
```

This was very problematic, as pushing now would take around 15 minutes.  The problem seemed to be that the entire working directory of each branch was rewritten, rather than just updating any files that had changed.  Even after adding a condition to check which branch had been pushed and only checkout that branch, if I pushed the branch other than the one that had been pushed previously, the push would still take around 10 minutes.  Obviously this is unacceptable.

My current attempt has 2 repositories (one intranet and one internet) on each server.  The hook I am running now looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`

  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    cd /x/intranet
    unset GIT_DIR
    git pull --verbose origin master
    echo "Changes pushed to production server."
  fi

  if [ "dev" == "$branch" ]; then
    cd /y/intranet
    unset GIT_DIR
    git pull --verbose origin dev
    echo "Changes pushed to dev server."
  fi

done
```

This hook is still taking longer than I feel that it should to run (almost 2 minutes, compared to about 4 seconds to run a pull in one of the repos myself).  Is there a problem with either of my implementations?  Or is there another method that will solve the issue?

EDIT: I was wondering if using the mounted drives in the git bash shell was possibly the issue?